# Custom HTTP Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I want to make a python script to automate JIRA-similar ticket responses.
For this, I am using json and requests library. Since http requests can be quite unreliable sometimes, I wanted to my script to retry the HTTP request in case it fails. So far I have this:

```
def openNewTicket(queueID, subject, content):
    post_url = "{}/ticket/".format(default_url)
    #Filling body OBJ
    myObj = { "ContentType": "text/plain",
              "Subject" : subject,
              "Content": content,
              "Queue": queueID,
              "CustomFields": { "33": "alarm", "26": "yes", "24": "technical incident" }
            }
    #Formatting obj to json
    jsonBody = json.dumps(myObj)
    print jsonBody
    try:
        response = requests.post(post_url, data=jsonBody, headers=authorization_header))
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        writeLog("{} - Created ticket {}\n".format(date, response['id']))
        rocketChat.sendChatMessage("modem", "Sucessfully created ticket {}".format(response['id']))
        return 0
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(1)
        return openNewTicket(queueID, subject, content)
```

The problem is: For some reason when I get 201 status code(created), it counts as an Exception and iterates again. Is there a way I can tell python that 201 status code is not an Exception?